# How to show notification badge icon on notification icon

Tags: flutter

```
   : Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              leading: Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/vr_logo.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        height: 10,
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
              title: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    dashboardViewModel.dashboardDetail.data?.garageName ?? "",
                    style: white40017,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    dashboardViewModel.dashboardDetail.data?.garageOwnerName ??
                        "",
                    style: white50014,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications_none_sharp),
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.push(const NotificationScreen());
                  },
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 5,
                  right: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6, vertical: 2),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text("1"),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            body: SizedBox(
              // color: Colors.amberAccent,
              height: size(context).height,
              width: size(context).width,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      trackingTopBar(context),
                      Text(
                        "Overview",
                        style: black60018,
                      ),
                      progressAndJob(context),
                      corsorelSliderBar(context),
                      amountBar(context),
                      customerStatusBar(context)
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
          ));
```

I wrote code to show notification  badge icon on top of notification but its coming separate left and right side in top bar.

[image]

This how its looking with my current code while i want just on right top corner touch with notification icon can any one help me how to adjust i tried but unable to do please help with this.
Thanks

Comment: You can use [badges package](https://pub.dev/packages/badges)

Comment: i tried using badge content but its not fit on right top its going end of tool bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
IconButton(
              icon: Badge(
                  label: Text('1'),
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.notifications_none_sharp,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  )),
              onPressed: () {
                context.push(const NotificationScreen());
              },
            ),
```

Comment: how we can change Badge color red to other ? because its coming default color

Comment: Badge have backgroundColor property, change it

Answer (score 0):

some changes in your Positioned widget. try or replace code with Positioned widget below code:

```
Positioned(
            top: 5,
            right: 5,
            child: Container(
              height: 18,
              width: 18,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                "1",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts by removing content or intentionally misformatting on-code as code, etc.